# From Raspberry PI using PIKA to put data to RabbitMQ

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rabbitmq

i have an issue.

For my final year project of uni i have my raspberry Pi taking sensor data, i need to put that data into my rabbitMQ service on another machine.
Currently i am using pika as a library to push the data into the queue. 
Right now i have an issue with connection, this is the error i am getting.

```
WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Could not connect due to "Connection timed out," retrying in 10 sec
ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:Could not connect: Connection timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TryOne.py", line 8, in <module>
connection = pika.AsyncoreConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('192.168.1.93'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 63, in __init__
super(BaseConnection, self).__init__(parameters, on_open_callback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 513, in __init__
self._connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 804, in _connect
    self._adapter_connect()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/asyncore_connection.py", line 96, in _adapter_connect
super(AsyncoreConnection, self)._adapter_connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 122, in _adapter_connect
self.params.retry_delay)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: 10.0
```

Any help with this problem is very much appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you have on the RabbitMQ logs? There should be clues there as to what's the problem